# How to use the updated useState value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I use DataGrid Material UI.
I want to delete the selected row by clicking on the button.
To do this, I get the ID value in the onRowSelected attribute, write it to the useState hook.
However, when I click on any row, the row I selected earlier is deleted, not the one I selected now.
I know that useState is asynchronous, but what should I do in this case?
I need to send the updated value in the delete request to the server, not the previous one.

```
      const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = useState([])
    
          const handleDeleteUser = (e) => {
                const config = {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                    }
                }
                e.preventDefault()
                axios
                    .delete(baseUrl + '/api/v1/users/' + `${selectionModel}/` , config)
                    .then((res) => {
                        swal({
                            title: "Are you sure?",
                            buttons: [true, "Do it!"],
                        })
                        updateData()
                    })
    
    <DataGrid
                          rows={datas}
                          columns={columns}
                          pageSize={10}
                          onRowSelected={(row) => {
                          setSelectionModel(row.data.id)
}} />
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpDLf.png)

Comment: The picture shows that I selected the 818 line, but state shows the previous 794, and the first time you click on it, it is empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've shown here I can't tell you exactly what the issue is, but I would suggest setting the selected id like you currently are here in the onRowSelected event, and then (if you're wanting to delete every time you click a row), use a useEffect hook with a dependency array to call your delete logic everytime that id changes. It would look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  deleteSelection(selectionModal)
}, [selectionModal]);

const deleteSelection = (id) => {
// your delete logic here
}
```

If you put together a working codepen I can help you more.

Comment: okay so in your example it's grabbing the incorrect value because the state hasn't been updated yet when the handleDeleteUser function gets called.

Ideally each row would have its own delete button that accepted the row id as a prop and then deleted based on that, but I'm not sure that's possible based on what you have here. I would try to refactor to using TableRows--here's a working demo that does exactly what you want https://codesandbox.io/s/q8or6zwm4j?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Oh, I was thinking about changing the table, but I was hoping there were other ways. Well, thank you for your help!